# Spring Transaction Doesn't Rollback

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

We have a Spring Transaction rollback issues, where rollback doesn't seems to be working.

Within my service layer method which is annotated with `@Transactional` I call three different `DAOImpl` classes to insert 3 records.
 The middle insert do a get from a 4th table to populate a description field but this get failed. I expect the first insert to rollback but it doesn't seems to be happening. 

**Few Points:**

1. The 'Get' method throws a Runtime Exception
2. We are using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` and `MySQL datasource` defined in `applicationContext.xml`. Beans are created in `Beans.xml` which is imported into `ApplicationContext.xml`
3. No `@Transactional` annotation in `DAO` layer
4. We have used `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` again in `applicationContext.xml`
5. We are using Spring 3.1

**UPDATE**:

Code snippets....

Service Class- This is somthing similar to what I have .... I tested with and without @Autowired. The transaction enable method is called within the service class.

```
public class CustomerService {

    //@Autowired
    CustomerOrderDAO customerOrderDAOImpl;
    //@Autowired
    CustomerItemDAO customerItemDAOImpl;
    //@Autowired
    CustomerPromotionDAO customerPromotionDAOImpl;
    //@Autowired
    PromotionDAO promotionDAOImpl;

    //other variables


    public CustomerOrder handleIncomingOrders(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        try {
            saveOrderDetails(customerOrder);
            .....
            return customerOrder;
        } catch (Exception e) //TO-DO catch proper exception 
        {
            //Send error response
            .......
            return customerOrder;
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveOrderDetails(CustomerOrder customerOrder) throws Exception {
            customerOrderDAOImpl.create(customerOrder);
            ....
            while (promotionsIterator.hasNext()) {
                customerPromotion.setPromotionName(promotionDAOImpl.getName(customerOrder.getPromotionId));
                customerPromotionDAOImpl.create(customerPromotion);
            }
            ......
            while (customerItemIterator.hasNext()) {
                customerItemDAOImpl.create(customerItem);
            }

    }
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code and the way you calling the Service method? from within the service or externally?  or any try catch you written yourself?

Comment: do you have a propagation set in the transaction definition

Comment: Do you have your connection in `autocommit` mode?

Comment: @rahul maindargi I have added the service class code.  Transactional annotation is not used anywhere in my application other than in the above method. So I thought propagation is not relevant.  Can you please tell me how to check that. I'll goolge in the meantime :)

Comment: What is the transaction propagation type? It could happen if it were set to `REQUIRES_NEW` like `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: @Lion I haven't use any. I do not have multiple transactions defined in the application .... in that case propagation is not applied. isn't it?

Comment: Right, the default is `REQUIRED`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behaviour of `@Transactional` is that transactional behaviour is added with a proxy around the object (the `CustomerService` in your example). From the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) (scroll down):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional.

In your example, an external call to the `handlingIncomingOrders()` passes through the proxy and hits the target object (an instance of the `CustomerService`). However, the subsequent call to `saveOrderDetails()` is a normal method call inside the target object, thus the transactional behaviour in the proxy is never invoked. However, if the `saveOrderDetails()` was called from another class, you will find that the transactional behaviour will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Although, I find it bit inconvenient. How can we change the default proxy mode?

Comment: I think the answer is `"Consider the use of AspectJ mode (see mode attribute in table below) if you expect self-invocations to be wrapped with transactions as well. In this case, there will not be a proxy in the first place; instead, the target class will be weaved (that is, its byte code will be modified) in order to turn @Transactional into runtime behavior on any kind of method.`

Comment: @Ish I usually make a clear definition of my transaction boundary by using the `@Transactional` annotation on the class level. Moreover I avoid or refactor any (public) method that calls the target object from itself, so that the transactions will be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in your case would be calling `saveOrderDetails(customerOrder);`  as `proxyBean.saveOrderDetails(customerOrder);` Where `proxybean is the Object on which`handleIncomingOrders` is being called.

If `CustomerService`  is `singleton` (Defualt scope) it can be as simple as adding below code to the Service class. (adding a self reference as autowired)

```
//@Autowired
CustomerService customerService; // As this is injected its a proxy
```

and in the Method use it as

```
 public CustomerOrder handleIncomingOrders(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
    try {
        customerService.saveOrderDetails(customerOrder);
        .....
        return customerOrder;
    } catch (Exception e) //TO-DO catch proper exception 
    {
        //Send error response
        .......
        return customerOrder;
    }
  }
```

If its scope is  `Prototype` the one of possible simple solution will be as follows.

```
public CustomerOrder handleIncomingOrders(CustomerOrder customerOrder, CustomerService customerService) {
    try {
        customerService.saveOrderDetails(customerOrder);
        .....
        return customerOrder;
    } catch (Exception e) //TO-DO catch proper exception 
    {
        //Send error response
        .......
        return customerOrder;
    }
  }
```

And where you are calling `handleIncomingOrders` use changes suggested in below code.

```
    bean.handleIncomingOrders(customerOrder); //Suppose this is old code 
Change it to 
    bean.handleIncomingOrders(customerOrder, bean);// THough it appears as we are sending reference to `THIS` as parameter whcihc can be unnecessary, in case of `Proxy`while inside your method `this` and `Passed reference` will point to different Obejects.
```