# Spring declarative transaction management and rollback handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

We are using Spring 4.x and Spring Data JPA with declarative transaction management, I have a Controller, Service and a Repository like below pseudo code.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class SampleService {

     @Autowired
     private SampleRepository sampleRepository;

     @Transactional
     public MyEntity saveMyEntity(MyEntity entity) {
      //do some business logic
      return sampleRepository.save(entity);
     }
}

public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService; 

    public String saveSample(@Valid MyEntity entity) {
       //Validation
       //If Valid
       sampleService.saveMyEntity(entity);
       //After saving do some view related rendering logic
       //Assume here view related rendering logic throws Exception
       return "view"  
    }
}
```

In the above code an error gets thrown after call to **sampleService.saveMyEntity(entity);** but the transaction doesn't mark for rollback, so end user will get an error page but behind the scene entity got persisted.

Is there any way i can rollback the transaction ?

Comment: Maybe this one could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167278/spring-transaction-doesnt-rollback

Comment: @Teo thanks but Not exactly the same issue, here my sampleService.saveMyEntity method returns without any exception. Here exception is happening after that service call and inside my controller.

Comment: The transaction is committed after saveMyEntity() completes. You cannot rollback after that. You would need to widen the scope of the transaction to include the additional logic.

Comment: @AlanHay to widen the scope i can have two approaches, one is like Shazin mentioned to add Transactional annotation at controller level or Opening transaction in a Filter. To be honest Transactional at controller level doesn't seems like a good practice and still have to cover the scope of exception thrown from other Filter chain, A possible solution  would be to start transaction in a filter and handle the commit and rollback manually. But i have no idea if there is any better alternative for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public String saveSample(@Valid MyEntity entity) {
   //Validation
   //If Valid
   sampleService.saveMyEntity(entity);
   //After saving do some view related rendering logic
   //Assume here view related rendering logic throws Exception
   return "view"  
}
```

Since the default Transaction Propagation is Required not Required new. Transaction will actually begin at `SampleController.saveSample()` and the same one will be used `SampleService.saveMyEntity()`. When an exception thrown from saveSample() the entire transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: its true if i widen the Transaction scope to controller it will work, but i think its not a good practice to add Transaction at controller level.