# Transaction not being rolled back in Springboot with postgres

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I read this post [Spring Transaction Doesn't Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167278/spring-transaction-doesnt-rollback) and I think I have a similar issue. My code structure is like this:

```
@Service
public class CoreProcessor {

  @Transactional
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 200000)
  public void run(){
    processingRequest();
  }

  public boolean processingRequest(JobRequest request){
    try{
      persistRequest(request);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      //some code here
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }

  private void persistRequest(JobRequest request){
    Job job = new Job();
    //...some other code to initialize Job using request...
    coreProcessorService.persistJob(job);  //this updates the job status and saves to db
    errorMethod(); // this method throws the error (NullPointerException)
  }
}
```

For persistJob in the coreProcessorService class it's pretty simple:

```
@Service
public class CoreProcessorService {
  public Job persistJob(Job job){
    return JobRepository.save(job);
  }
}
```

Since the `errorMethod()` throws an error, I want all the changes in `persistJob()` should be rolled back. But currently it's being updated and saved. How can I fix this?

What I've tried:
adding `@Transactional` to `persistRequest()` or `persistJob()` or both.
using `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Please show us code for the CoreProcessorService and the code that is calling CoreProcessor.

Comment: @LeeGreiner there's a scheduler on the run() method. In the service class, all that method does is repository.save(job).

Comment: You haven't shown what processingRequest() actually does. If it is actually calling processingRequest(Job) then any exception thrown by persistRequest(JobRequest) is caught and whatever is done in 'some code here' is executed. If the exception is not propicated the transaction completes successfully and does not roll back.

Comment: The Transaction started by `CoreProcessor.run()` method, and there is no exception thrown out of that method, that's why it doesn't rollback. You should remove the catch exception or leverage the whole persist operation to `CoreProcessorService` class(mark transaction there) and catch exception in run method.

Comment: The only place I can see that may be introducing this issue is in ```JobRepository.save(job)```. Can you show us this class?

Answer (score 3):

The Transaction started by `CoreProcessor.run()` method, and there is no exception thrown out of that method, that's why it doesn't rollback. You should remove the catch exception or leverage the whole persist operation to `CoreProcessorService` class and also start transaction here. Then catch exception in run method to send/log errors.

```
@Service
public class CoreProcessorService {

  @Transactional
  public void persistRequest(JobRequest request){
    Job job = new Job();
    //...some other code to initialize Job using request...
    jobRepository.save(job);  //this updates the job status and saves to db
    errorMethod(); // this method throws the error (NullPointerException)
  }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CoreProcessor {

  @Autowired
  private CoreProcessorService coreProcessorService;

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 200000)
  public void run(){
    try {
      coreProcessorService.processingRequest();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      // handle failer
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

> Note that by default, rollback happens for runtime, unchecked
> exceptions only. The checked exception does not trigger a rollback of
> the transaction

So yeah, if you want to automatic rollback in `run()` method, you can change `throw new Exception()` to `throw new RuntimeException();`

Otherwise, you have to specify the checked Exception on `run` method to tell transaction roll back for it

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
```

Comment: Actually they throw another exception in the catch block in processingRequest... So it should propagate back to run(). I updated the code for this change. Is there anything else you might suggest?

Comment: @Nathan I updated the answer, that's another problem you might need to know